# Edittext in a ListView repeates information on scroll - Android

Tags: android

I've been searching for hours trying to solve this problem but I couldn't find something useful for my case here's the code for one of my edittext " I have two "
The problem: when I have enough items on the list that I need to scroll down/up the items remove the old information and replaces it with the wrong information.

before I post the code , I basically have a button " not in the listview " when it's pressed it controls the edittext via:

```
text.setFocusable(bool);
text.setFocusableInTouchMode(bool);
```

so it's basically the user can edit then click on the button again to remove the background of edittext and let it behave like a textview.

now here's the code for one of the edittext in getview(..)

```
   if (convertView == null)
    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_shopping, parent,false);

        final EditText text = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_shopping_items);
        text.setText(item.getmName());

        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item.setmName(s.toString());
            }
        });
```

I removed some of the code that it isn't useful it'll just make it long.

The problem is in the textwatcher , when I remove it it works fine but I can't edit anything!

the two solutions I found:

1- get rid of the recycling , problem ? it hits the performance.
2- get rid of the textwatcher , problem ? I can't edit the text

---

Edit:

I used something else to edit the text instead of my old way , just enable the long click and pop up a dialog and control everything from there , while it's not as fast as the old way but I couldn't find a solution to this except for using the onLongClick(..) :(

Comment: and what is requirement ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K , basically I want to solve this problem , I want to keep the editing functionality which requires a textwatcher , the problem is that the textwatcher is what causes all of this when I scroll down or up.

Comment: Input methods in list views are not recommended (except checkboxes). consider using a scroll view and manual created rows.

Comment: @user3504658: what is `item` ?

Comment: @user3504658: first use `ViewHolder pattern` in `getView` method then i will give some suggestion to achieve current requirement. thanks

Comment: @Xyaren I think it'll hit the performance that way , I like the listview and everything is working except for this problem :(

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K , item is an object which points to another object in an arraylist , basically like saying: object item = list.get(pos);  , using viewholder is the same as what I'm doing right now , it's both used to recycle views.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due views being reused via `convertView`. Whenever the convertView is null, you are setting the values which is correct. But, what you are missing is that when the convertView is not null, you are not doing 
anything. When the convertView is not null, it means the view is already there and you don't need to inflate it again. But you will still need to set the values to the view, otherwise wrong data will be show as the views from some other position will be reused here.

So, basically what you need to do is inflate the convertView whenever it is null and set the data to the view at all cases.

```
   if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_shopping, parent,false);
      }


        final EditText text = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_shopping_items);
        text.setText(item.getmName());

        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item.setmName(s.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm so sorry , my code is the same as yours but I put {} in my post which is wrong , I edit it , the problem occurs even then.